# Issue with duplicate columns in MYSQL query results

Tags: mysql

The MYSQL statement below works as intended, listing the number of instances where profiles are used in resumes.

However, it returns the profile_id column twice. In the second instance wherever a profile is not used in any resume, profile_id displays as NULL even though there is a value.

I believe that I may need to add DISTINCT to the query, but where I've tried it hasn't worked.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(pc.postcount, 0) AS postcount 
    FROM profiles 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT resumes.profile_id, COUNT(resumes.resume_id) AS postcount 
                       FROM resumes 
                       WHERE 1 
                       GROUP BY resumes.profile_id) pc 
            ON pc.profile_id=profiles.profile_id 
    WHERE profiles.user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `profile_id` column exists in both your `profiles` table and in your subquery on `resumes` and, since you're using `SELECT *`, you get it returned twice.

Instead, explicitly list all of your columns in the `SELECT`, including appropriate table prefixes.

```
SELECT profiles.profile_id, ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Just changing to SELECT profiles.profile_id,profiles.name,... did it

Answer (score 0):

list all of your columns in the SELECT with appropriate table prefixes.

Try Below:

```
SELECT profiles.*,pc.*, COALESCE(pc.postcount, 0) AS postcount 
    FROM profiles 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT resumes.profile_id, COUNT(resumes.resume_id) AS postcount 
                       FROM resumes 
                       WHERE 1 
                       GROUP BY resumes.profile_id) pc 
            ON pc.profile_id=profiles.profile_id 
    WHERE profiles.user_id = ?
```